# Google maps overlay image not entirely transparent

Tags: image, google-maps-api-3, overlay, transparency

Here is my code:

(link removed)

As you can see the overlay image is not entirely transparent. When I open up that image in a picture viewer the transparency is total, not as it is rendered (washed white) on my maps.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Since the short-link is broken (and it has been removed anyway) this question needs to be closed and deleted. I will try to close it as a first step. Please do not vandalise your questions in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a CSS-issue, there is a background-color for the image applied, defined for the selector

```
.post-body img, .post-body .tr-caption-container, .Profile img, .Image img, .BlogList .item-thumbnail img
```

You may either change this CSS and make it more distinct, so that it not affects the image, or add this to `TQOverlay.prototype.onAdd`:

```
img.style.background='transparent';
img.style.border='none';
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. I thought it was the image that it was not OK